# How to debug My Phonegap App on android Phone Connected With Usb Data Cable from Eclipse Ide

Tags: cordova

I am Running Eclipse Ide on ubuntu and in that My sdk manager showing google usb driver disabled for linux os so how to unable it and debug my app from online mobile device connected to desktop.

I had also done preliminary settings in my mobile phone

i.e I enabled USB Debugging in my phone.

please help me out.

Comment: is there any one who can help me

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging